# Flask App | render template and start automatic download afterwards

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

I created a **Flask app**, which receives an input file, extracts the content, converts it to another format and returns a compressed file with the converted content.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', "POST"])
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', "POST"])
def home():
    form = UploadFileForm()
    file = form.file.data
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        file.save(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(
        file.filename)))

        # 1. unzip files in directory
        unzip(file.filename)

        # 2. starts conversion process
        conversion_status = converter().failed_files

        # 3. compress generated DICOM files into export .zip file
        zip_dir("static/results/conversion")

        # 4. routes to downloading page with corresponding download action
        return redirect(url_for('download'))

    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

So far everything works. Currently I'm routing in step 4 to another function, which renders a result page, telling, if the conversion was fine. It also prints the export files and by clicking on them, the can be downloaded.

```
@app.route('/download')
def download():
   return render_template('download.html', files=os.listdir('static/results/export'), status=conversion_status)

@app.route('/download/<filename>')
def download_file(filename):
   return send_from_directory('static/results/export', filename)
```

Because I'm running that app on a azure web app url, I want to change the process into:

1. Rendering the result page
2. Downloading the content automatically afterwards, without user input

Like this:

```
return render_template('download.html', files=os.listdir('static/results/export'), status=conversion_status)
return send_from_directory('static/results/export', filename)
```

But I do not have any idea how to render two things after each other

Answer (score 0):

It's not feasible to render two things consecutively within one endpoint.
However, there is a possibility to download the file automatically using JavaScript.

To find your current result within the list of files, you can pass the name as a parameter to the endpoint for the results.

```py
return redirect(url_for('download', f=filename))
```

Within the endpoint, you ask for this parameter and pass it on to the template along with the list of files found. You can use a simple comparison to identify the file and use an attribute to mark the anchor for download as current.

```py
@app.route('/download')
def download():
    current = request.args.get('f')
    files = os.listdir('static/results/export')
    return render_template('download.html', **locals())
```

```html
<ul>
  {% for file in files -%}
  <li>
    <a
      class="{{ ('', 'dwl-current')[current and current == file] }}"
      href="{{ url_for('download_file', filename=file) }}"
      download
    >{{file}}</a></li>
  {% endfor -%}
</ul>
```

If you add the anchor to run the download, it is now possible to click it automatically.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  (() => {
    const elem = document.querySelector('a.dwl-current');
    elem && elem.click();
  })();
</script>
```